# i am trying to use DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer but not working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, dead-letter

2020-04-28 18:49:05.388 ERROR 14531 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer    : Dead-letter publication failed for: ProducerRecord(topic=LP_EVENT.DLT, partition=4, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-topic, value = [76, 80, 95, 69, 86, 69, 78, 84]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-partition, value = [0, 0, 0, 4]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-offset, value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp, value = [0, 0, 1, 113, -66, -64, -61, 43]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp-type, value = [67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 84, 105, 109, 101]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-fqcn, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110, 70, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-message, value = [76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 32, 109, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 32, 39, 112, 117, 98, 108, 105, 99, 32, 118, 111, 105, 100, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 120, 109, 46, 108, 112, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 97, 112, 105, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 112, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 40, 111, 114, 103, 46, 120, 109, 46, 108, 112, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 46, 118, 111, 46, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 80, 97, 121, 108, 111, 97, 100, 44, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 115, 117, 112, 112, 111, 114, 116, 46, 65, 99, 107, 110, 111, 119, 108, 101, 100, 103, 109, 101, 110, 116, 41, 32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 39, 32, 116, 104, 114, 101, 119, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-stacktrace, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110, 70, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 32, 109, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 32, 39, 112, 117, 98, 108, 105, 99, 32, 118, 111, 105, 100, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 120, 109, 46, 108, 112, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 97, 112, 105, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 112, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 40, 111, 114, 103, 46, 120, 109, 46, 108, 112, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 46, 118, 111, 46, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 80, 97, 121, 108, 111, 97, 100, 44, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 115, 117, 112, 112, 111, 114, 116, 46, 65, 99, 107, 110, 111, 119, 108, 101, 100, 103, 109, 101, 110, 116, 41, 32, 116, 104, 114, 111, 119, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 39, 32, 116, 104, 114, 101, 119, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 100, 101, 99, 111, 114, 97, 116, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 55, 49, 54, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 69, 114, 114, 111, 114, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 55, 48, 52, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 100, 111, 73, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 54, 50, 49, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 100, 111, 73, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 87, 105, 116, 104, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 115, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 53, 52, 57, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 52, 53, 55, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 50, 48, 55, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 112, 111, 108, 108, 65, 110, 100, 73, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 57, 54, 54, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 114, 117, 110, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 57, 48, 49, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 110, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 46, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 111, 114, 115, 36, 82, 117, 110, 110, 97, 98, 108, 101, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 99, 97, 108, 108, 40, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 111, 114, 115, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 53, 49, 49, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 110, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 46, 70, 117, 116, 117, 114, 101, 84, 97, 115, 107, 46, 114, 117, 110, 40, 70, 117, 116, 117, 114, 101, 84, 97, 115, 107, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 50, 54, 54, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 84, 104, 114, 101, 97, 100, 46, 114, 117, 110, 40, 84, 104, 114, 101, 97, 100, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 55, 52, 56, 41, 10, 67, 97, 117, 115, 101, 100, 32, 98, 121, 58, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 120, 109, 46, 108, 112, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 97, 112, 105, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 112, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 40, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 51, 53, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 115, 117, 110, 46, 114, 101, 102, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 78, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 73, 109, 112, 108, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 48, 40, 78, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101, 32, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 115, 117, 110, 46, 114, 101, 102, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 78, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 73, 109, 112, 108, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 78, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 73, 109, 112, 108, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 54, 50, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 115, 117, 110, 46, 114, 101, 102, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 68, 101, 108, 101, 103, 97, 116, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 73, 109, 112, 108, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 68, 101, 108, 101, 103, 97, 116, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 65, 99, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 73, 109, 112, 108, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 52, 51, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 114, 101, 102, 108, 101, 99, 116, 46, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 52, 57, 56, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 46, 104, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 73, 110, 118, 111, 99, 97, 98, 108, 101, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 46, 100, 111, 73, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 73, 110, 118, 111, 99, 97, 98, 108, 101, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 55, 49, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 46, 104, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 73, 110, 118, 111, 99, 97, 98, 108, 101, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 73, 110, 118, 111, 99, 97, 98, 108, 101, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 77, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 50, 48, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 40, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 52, 56, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 72, 97, 110, 100, 108, 101, 114, 40, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 51, 48, 52, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 111, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 40, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 56, 54, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 111, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 40, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 53, 49, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 108, 97, 109, 98, 100, 97, 36, 111, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 36, 48, 40, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 50, 48, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 114, 101, 116, 114, 121, 46, 115, 117, 112, 112, 111, 114, 116, 46, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 46, 100, 111, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 101, 40, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 50, 56, 55, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 114, 101, 116, 114, 121, 46, 115, 117, 112, 112, 111, 114, 116, 46, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 46, 101, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 101, 40, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 50, 49, 49, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 111, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 40, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 49, 52, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 111, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 40, 82, 101, 116, 114, 121, 105, 110, 103, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 65, 100, 97, 112, 116, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 52, 48, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 100, 111, 73, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 79, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 54, 55, 48, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 79, 110, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 54, 53, 51, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 36, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 100, 111, 73, 110, 118, 111, 107, 101, 82, 101, 99, 111, 114, 100, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 40, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 67, 111, 110, 116, 97, 105, 110, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 54, 48, 56, 41, 10, 9, 46, 46, 46, 32, 56, 32, 109, 111, 114, 101, 10])], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=Hello(name=Ankit, Payload=[{"serialNo": "3545145628662", "eventTime": "2020-04-22 23:59:59"}]), timestamp=null)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:412) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:451) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.append(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:508) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.append(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:531) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.tryAppend(ProducerBatch.java:106) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:224) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:917) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:856) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:590) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:404) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:241) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:214) [spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:159) [spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:53) [spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordTracker.skip(FailedRecordTracker.java:101) [spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.SeekUtils.lambda$doSeeks$2(SeekUtils.java:75) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.SeekUtils.doSeeks(SeekUtils.java:72) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:198) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1704) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1621) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1549) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1457) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1207) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:966) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:901) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_242]

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> Magic v1 does not support record headers

record headers are introduced in Apache Kafka 0.11.0.0. Can it be that your brokers are older or that the topic you are using is using an older message format (note, that if a topic is created with an old broker and the brokers are updated, the older message format is kept if not explicitly updated, too).